# Failed to retrieve the message from inbox in the real device

Tags: android, cursor

I am trying to get the inbox and sent messages. For this I have written my code below. My code runs well in the emulator but it doesn't work when I try to run it on a real device. It fails to collect the inbox messages even though there are messages in the inbox. I'd like to add that I want make the query with the contact number to retrieve the messages.

```java
Cursor cursorsender = contentResolverSender.query(
            Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), null, "address = "
                    + senderAddress, null, null);
```

```java
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
            null, "address = " + senderAddress, null, null);
```

my cursorsender.movetofirst() is returning false.